# MySQL - help writing search query syntax

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table(named Assignments) that looks like this:

```
Username    RandomWebsite1   RandomWebsite2   RandomWebsite3
-----------------------------------------------------------------
bugs bunny        1                0                1
elmer fudd        0                1                1
popeye            1                1                0
elvis             1                1                1
bruce lee         0                1                0
```

What I need is three different query's like:  (ill do it in English language instead of my bad attempt at writing the syntax"

1. I need to add the usernames to a listbox if I want to search for all the people with RandomWebsite1 assigned(my program recognizes 1 as the value that it is assigned)
2. I need to search for "RandomWebsite1" and anyone who has "1" in that field needs to be added to my listbox.  What would the MySQL syntax look like?
3. I need to search ALL COLUMNS in the table, no matter the name of the column since it can be generated randomly, and anyone who has "1" in that field needs to be added to my listbox.  What would the MySQL syntax look like?  I imagine there would have to be a wildcard in the somewhere like:

   `SHOW 'Username' WHERE * = 1` or something.

I know my database design probably is bad, but it is what it is and cannot fix it now, but am open to suggestions.  Basically have like 5000 users in this table.

Edited:

I need to be able to type "bugs bunny" into my search field... then it searches this table and will list me ALL of the websites that have been assigned (anything with a "1")...  I hope this helps... thanks again.

Comment: I'm actually a bit confused by what you want, but from what I understood, you need something like this. `SELECT username FROM Assignments WHERE RandomWebsite1 = '1';`

Comment: "...no matter the name of the column since it can be generated randomly…" You're generating column names randomly? That doesn't sound like the best idea.

Comment: are you absolutely stuck with this DB schema? Because generating column names randomly is going to make things very messy. It would be better to create another table that lists the name of the websites, along with a website ID (primary key for that table) then another table that links the websites to the users....

Comment: Ditto @A.O.'s updated comment. That's definitely the design you should go with.

Comment: A.O.  I think I know what you're saying for the table with all of the websites listed.  How would you suggest the table for the "UserAssignments" look?

Comment: i edited above also....  the bottom has a clarified question.

Comment: You could make it as simple as two fields (user_id, website_id). You wouldnt have any more 1's or 0's, just matches or no matches....so to query for bugsbunny it would look something like this: `SELECT u.username FROM Users u JOIN UserAssignments ua ON ua.user_id = u.user_id JOIN assignments a ON a.website_id = ua.website_id WHERE a.website_name = 'bugsbunny'`

Comment: What I have right now is two tables.  this userassignments table and a websites table lists the website address, who added it, and when it was added.  So it sort of does what you're implying.  I just don't know of a better way to handle the user assignments table.... basically why im here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok to make it clear, you should have three tables to accomplish this.
First table:

**Users**

```
User_id      UserName
---------------------
0            bugsbunny
1            elmer fudd
2            popeye
```

Second table:

**Assignments**

```
Assignment_id        website_name
-------------------------------------
0                      www.url1.com
1                      www.url2.com
2                      www.url3.com
```

And finally:

**UserAssignments**

```
User_id         Assignment_id
------------------------------
0                   1
0                   2
```

With this setup, you can add as many `Users` and `Assignments` as you like, and you can link them together through the `UserAssignment` table, WITHOUT generating random columns dynamically!

So to see all of the websites that have been assigned to user `bugsbunny` you would do this:

```
SELECT a.website_name FROM Assignments a 
JOIN UserAssignments ua ON ua.Assignment_id = a.Assignment_id
JOIN Users u ON u.User_id = ua.User_id
WHERE u.UserName = 'bugsbunny'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the query:

```
SELECT 'RandomWebsite1'
FROM Assignments
WHERE Username = 'bugs bunny' AND RandomWebsite1
UNION
SELECT 'RandomWebsite2'
FROM Assignments
WHERE Username = 'bugs bunny' AND RandomWebsite2
UNION
SELECT 'RandomWebsite3'
FROM Assignments
WHERE Username = 'bugs bunny' AND RandomWebsite3
```

Every time you modify the "website" columns, update the query too.